# Spark DataFrame: How to specify schema when writing as Avro

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I want to write a DataFrame in Avro format using a provided Avro schema rather than Spark's auto-generated schema. How can I tell Spark to use my custom schema on write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After applying the patch in https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/222/, I was able to specify a schema on write as follows:

```
df.write.option("forceSchema", myCustomSchemaString).avro("/path/to/outputDir")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below method helps.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType( StructField("title", StringType, true) ::StructField("averageRating", DoubleType, false) ::StructField("numVotes", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)

titleMappedDF.write.option("avroSchema", schema.toString).avro("/home/cloudera/workspace/movies/avrowithschema")

Example:


Download data from below site. https://datasets.imdbws.com/
Download the movies data title.ratings.tsv.gz
Copy to below location. /home/cloudera/workspace/movies/title.ratings.tsv.gz


Start Spark-shell and type below command.

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val title = sqlContext.read.text("file:///home/cloudera/Downloads/movies/title.ratings.tsv.gz")
scala> title.limit(5).show
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|tconst averageRat...|
|  tt0000001    5.8 1350|
|   tt0000002   6.5 157|
|   tt0000003   6.6 933|
|    tt0000004  6.4 93|
+--------------------+

val titlerdd = title.rdd

case class Title(titleId:String, averageRating:Float, numVotes:Int)

val titlefirst = titlerdd.first
val titleMapped = titlerdd.filter(e=> e!=titlefirst).map(e=> {
   val rowStr = e.getString(0)
   val splitted = rowStr.split("\t")
   val titleId = splitted(0).trim
   val averageRating = scala.util.Try(splitted(1).trim.toFloat) getOrElse(0.0f)
   val numVotes = scala.util.Try(splitted(2).trim.toInt) getOrElse(0)
   Title(titleId, averageRating, numVotes)
})

val titleMappedDF =  titleMapped.toDF

scala> titleMappedDF.limit(2).show
+---------+-------------+--------+
|  titleId|averageRating|numVotes|
+---------+-------------+--------+
|tt0000001|          5.8|    1350|
|tt0000002|          6.5|     157|
+---------+-------------+--------+


import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType( StructField("title", StringType, true) ::StructField("averageRating", DoubleType, false) ::StructField("numVotes", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)

titleMappedDF.write.option("avroSchema", schema.toString).avro("/home/cloudera/workspace/movies/avrowithschema")
```

Comment: The "avroSchema" option has no effect for `.write`. It's only used for `.read` by the `DefaultSource`. See https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/55d4f08ad8f0cbc9d303acd30e948d0002309ebc/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/DefaultSource.scala.